# How to update Label text when downloading Images using GCD in IOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, uilabel, grand-central-dispatch

I use GCD to download Images from server and updates the processing on UILabel then print the label to the screen (ex: it will print to the screen : "Downloading: 3/15 Images")

But at the beginning the label is : "Downloading: 0/15 Images". Then when it finish downloading, the label is "Downloading: 15/15 Images".The user cant see the download processing.

What I want is user can see the processing like: 
"Downloading: 1/15 Images","Downloading: 2/15 Images"."Downloading: 3/15 Images",...,"Downloading: 15/15 Images".

This is my code:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //Here your non-main thread.
        NSString *text;

        for (int i = 0;i<[self.pageImages count];i++){
            NSString *image = [self.pageImages objectAtIndex:i];

            [dataManage downloadImagesFromUrl: image ];
            text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@“Downloading %d/%d”,i,self.pageImages.count];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Here you returns to main thread.
            [downloadLabel setText:text];
        });
    });
```

Comment: you have to write the setText code inside the loop.

Comment: I set text inside the loop but it just print: ""Downloading: 1/15 Images" and nothing else. I read somewhere they mention that we must update the UI in the main thread. But when I NSlog the "text" It will print what I want.

Comment: I ran into almost exact same problem. What I ended up doing was instead of using a "for" loop I used NSTimer and spaced the events to be .5 seconds apart. Try that and your will see all the updates show up in your label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //Here you returns to main thread.
    [downloadLabel setText:text];
});
```

inside the `for` loop so that the UI is updated after each download (rather than only at the end of all iterations).

Comment: I set text inside the loop but it just print: ""Downloading: 1/15 Images" and nothing else. I read somewhere they mention that we must update the UI in the main thread. But when I NSlog the "text" It will print what I want.

Comment: @tommy because there are probably only one page image ready when you run the loop. You should update the label when you get a download call back possibly from somewhere here `[dataManage downloadImagesFromUrl: image ];`.

Comment: Using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue  ...` should mean you don't need a timer as it pushes the UI update onto the main queue (and away from the for loop). You did move the whole block of code into the loop, yes?

Comment: Move the whole block of code into the loop is the correct answer. Thanks very much Wain. Vote for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code inside the dispatch_async block:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
   [downloadLabel setText:text];
}];
```

Comment: This is a different way of putting something onto the main thread queue, but it doesn't solve the problem as it's still added to the queue at the wrong time (too late)